# Backtick as a non-dead key?

Tags: macos, keyboard

On my mac (azerty keyboard layout), I have this key: `` ` ``, but I'd like it to place the backtick immediately, as I don't have a need to place it on letters.

How can I get my mac to make touching the `` ` `` button place the backtick immediately? I use it a lot in Q&A here and have never used it to place it on a letter.

Comment: Please let us know the keyboard layout you use (French, Arabic?) as well as the OS X/macOS version in order to help you.

Comment: Belgian (French) I think is the official name, but it's exactly the same as the French one I think. Latest version of macOS

Comment: @TomGewecke I often forget it. I'd like to just not have to type it, as I don't type it on top of a letter

Comment: Have you tried [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)? If you're on 10.12, [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements).

Answer (score 1):

A keyboard layout called Belgian2 with the backtick you want can be found at [this page](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wp2fonqswo14egr/Belgian2.keylayout?dl=0).

Install the .keylayout file (remove any .txt extension if there is one) in Home/Library/Keyboard Layouts.  Then go to System Preferences/Keyboard/Input Sources and use the plus and add buttons to activate it (look in the Others folder).  Then select in the "flag" menu at the top right of the finder.

To get to Home/Library, you need to hold down the option key while doing Finder > Go.  You can also install in Library/Keyboard Layouts to make available to all users.

Comment: What do I do with this file?

Comment: @vrwim instructions added now